# MergeSorted array has an extra zero at first position and it only shows that fault when testing on big arrays

Tags: c, arrays, testing, int, mergesort

So the problem is that I've made this MergeSort that works for smaller arrays but not for bigger arrays
in bigger arrays it inserts an extra zero in the beginning
as you can see below.

```
------------------------------------------------
SORTING TESTS: START
Problem:                323, 389, 881, 821, 663, 964, 958, 68, 988, 624, 44, 288, 226, 317, 347, 840, 241, 940, 8, 461, 125, 686, 917, 400, 378, 158, 171, 823, 804, 331, 930, 717, 189, 850, 790, 481, 983, 152, 575, 408, 888, 570, 872, 671, 734, 671, 850, 428, 36, 306, 700, 916, 868, 781, 463, 385, 820, 606, 727, 584, 563, 815, 717, 138, 759, 975, 177, 293, 762, 686, 498, 8, 992, 519, 212, 686, 608, 663, 656, 545, 618, 968, 710, 150, 534, 283, 506, 769, 794, 413, 495, 771, 210, 365, 125, 233, 272, 363, 692, 95, 
Solution:               8, 8, 36, 44, 68, 95, 125, 125, 138, 150, 152, 158, 171, 177, 189, 210, 212, 226, 233, 241, 272, 283, 288, 293, 306, 317, 323, 331, 347, 363, 365, 378, 385, 389, 400, 408, 413, 428, 461, 463, 481, 495, 498, 506, 519, 534, 545, 563, 570, 575, 584, 606, 608, 618, 624, 656, 663, 663, 671, 671, 686, 686, 686, 692, 700, 710, 717, 717, 727, 734, 759, 762, 769, 771, 781, 790, 794, 804, 815, 820, 821, 823, 840, 850, 850, 868, 872, 881, 888, 916, 917, 930, 940, 958, 964, 968, 975, 983, 988, 992, 
Sorted(Testing):        0, 8, 8, 36, 44, 68, 95, 125, 125, 138, 150, 152, 158, 171, 177, 189, 210, 212, 226, 233, 241, 272, 283, 288, 293, 306, 317, 323, 331, 347, 363, 365, 378, 385, 389, 400, 408, 413, 428, 461, 463, 481, 495, 498, 506, 519, 534, 545, 563, 570, 575, 584, 606, 608, 618, 624, 656, 663, 663, 671, 671, 686, 686, 686, 692, 700, 710, 717, 717, 727, 734, 759, 762, 769, 771, 781, 790, 794, 804, 815, 820, 821, 823, 840, 850, 850, 868, 872, 881, 888, 916, 917, 930, 940, 958, 964, 968, 975, 983, 988, 992, 
Sorted(InsertionSort):  8, 8, 36, 44, 68, 95, 125, 125, 138, 150, 152, 158, 171, 177, 189, 210, 212, 226, 233, 241, 272, 283, 288, 293, 306, 317, 323, 331, 347, 363, 365, 378, 385, 389, 400, 408, 413, 428, 461, 463, 481, 495, 498, 506, 519, 534, 545, 563, 570, 575, 584, 606, 608, 618, 624, 656, 663, 663, 671, 671, 686, 686, 686, 692, 700, 710, 717, 717, 727, 734, 759, 762, 769, 771, 781, 790, 794, 804, 815, 820, 821, 823, 840, 850, 850, 868, 872, 881, 888, 916, 917, 930, 940, 958, 964, 968, 975, 983, 988, 992, 
assertion "isArrEqual(sortThis, &solutionArr[1], solutionArr[0])" failed: file "
/cygdrive/c/src/universal-repos/datastructures-and-algorithms/main.c", line 119,
 function: sortingTest
a
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Below you can see the testing and implementation of the mergeSort
I believe the fault lies in the merging function but if I knew what I was doing then I would've managed to fix this bug of mine.

```
int *mergeSortShell(const int *const sortThis, int size) {
    if(sortThis == NULL || size < 1){
        return NULL;
    }
    int * copyArr = arrCopy(sortThis, 0, size);
    mergeSort(copyArr, 0, size);
    return copyArr;


}

void mergeSort(int * sort, int left, int right) {
    //the array and left  should be zero and right bound right you be the size of the array
    if (sort == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if (right > left) {

        int middle = (right - left);
        if (middle % 2 != 0){
            middle--;
        }
        middle = middle / 2 + left;
        mergeSort(sort, left, middle);
        mergeSort(sort, middle + 1, right);
        merge(sort, left, middle, right);
    }

}
void merge(int *mergeThis, int left, int middle, int right) {

    if (mergeThis == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    int leftSize = (middle - left) + 1;
    int rightSize = right - middle;
    int i, j, k; //iterators to be used throughout the function

    int leftArray[leftSize + 1], rightArray[rightSize + 1];//tempArrays
    leftArray[leftSize] = INT_MAX;
    rightArray[rightSize] = INT_MAX;

    for (i = 0; i < leftSize; i++) {
        leftArray[i] = mergeThis[left + i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rightSize; i++) {
        rightArray[i] = mergeThis[middle + 1 + i];
    }

    i = 0;//index of leftArray
    j = 0;//index of rightArray
    k = left;//index of sortCpy

    while (i < leftSize && j < rightSize) {
        if (leftArray[i] <= rightArray[j]) {
            mergeThis[k] = leftArray[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            mergeThis[k] = rightArray[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    //if any of the the right or left has remaining elements
    //this will run
    while (i < leftSize) {
        mergeThis[k] = leftArray[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j < rightSize) {
        mergeThis[k] = rightArray[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }

}





int *arrCopy(const int *const arrayPtr, int leftBound, int size) {//leftbound should be left at zero if you want it
    // to copy the whole array
    int *sortCpy = NULL;
    sortCpy = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (size - leftBound));
    if (arrayPtr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0, j = leftBound; i < (size - leftBound) && j < size; i++, j++) {
        sortCpy[i] = arrayPtr[j];
    }
    //memcpy(sortCpy, arrayPtr, size * sizeof(int));
    if (isArrEqual(sortCpy, arrayPtr, size) == false) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return sortCpy;
}

bool sortingTest() {
    printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("SORTING TESTS: START\n");

    const int l1[] = {3, 1, 5, 10, 8, 7};
    const int l1solution[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10};
    const int l2[] = {5, 2, 9, 6, 1, 2};
    const int l2solution[] = {1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 9};
    const int pNum[] = {1, 9, 9, 5, 0, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0, 9, 6};
    const int pNumSolution[] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9};

    assert(isArrEqual(l1, l1, 6) == true);
    assert(isArrEqual(l1, l1solution, 6) == false);
    assert(isArrEqual(l2, l2solution, 6) == false);
    assert(isArrEqual(NULL, NULL, 5) == false);
    assert(arrPrint(NULL, INT_MIN) == false);





//    assert(isArrEqual(pNum, pNumSolved, 12));

    assert(load_file(NULL) == NULL);

    char sortingProblem[] = {"../sorting_problems/test-10-1-problem"};
    char sortingSolution[] = {"../sorting_problems/test-10-1-solution"};
    const int * const problemArr = load_file(sortingProblem);
    const int * const solutionArr = load_file(sortingSolution);

    assert(problemArr != NULL);
    assert(solutionArr != NULL);

    int *copyTest = NULL;
    copyTest = arrCopy(&solutionArr[1], 0, solutionArr[0]);
    assert(isArrEqual(copyTest, &solutionArr[1], solutionArr[0]));
    free(copyTest);

    copyTest = arrCopy(&problemArr[1], 0, problemArr[0]);
    assert(isArrEqual(copyTest, &problemArr[1], problemArr[0]));
    free(copyTest);
    int *sortThis = NULL;
    int *reference = NULL;

    //----------------MERGE SORT START----------------------
    assert(mergeSortShell(NULL, INT_MIN) == NULL);
    assert(mergeSortShell(l1, INT_MIN) == NULL);

    sortThis = mergeSortShell(l1, (sizeof(l1) / sizeof(int)));
    assert(sortThis != NULL);
    assert(isArrEqual(sortThis, l1solution, sizeof(l1) / sizeof(int)));
    free(sortThis);

    sortThis = mergeSortShell(l2, (sizeof(l2) / sizeof(int)));
    assert(sortThis != NULL);
    assert(isArrEqual(sortThis, l2solution, sizeof(l2) / sizeof(int)));
    free(sortThis);

    sortThis = mergeSortShell(pNum, (sizeof(pNum) / sizeof(int)));
    assert(sortThis != NULL);
    assert(isArrEqual(sortThis, pNumSolution, sizeof(pNum) / sizeof(int)));
    free(sortThis);

    sortThis = mergeSortShell(&problemArr[1], problemArr[0]);
    assert(sortThis != NULL);

    //region Status
    printf("Problem: \t\t\t\t");
    arrPrint(&problemArr[1], problemArr[0]);
    printf("Solution:\t\t\t\t");
    arrPrint(&solutionArr[1], solutionArr[0]);
    printf("Sorted(Testing):\t\t");
    arrPrint(sortThis, solutionArr[0]+1);
    //endregion

    assert(isArrEqual(sortThis, &solutionArr[1], solutionArr[0]));
    free(sortThis);
    /**/
    // ----------------MERGE SORT END------------------------
    //----------------QUICK SORT START----------------------
    //Might not implement
    //----------------QUICK SORT END------------------------

    free((int*)problemArr);
    free((int*)solutionArr);

    printf("SORTING TESTS: END\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
    return 0;
}

int main() {


    printf("------------------------START OF TESTS------------------------\n");
    altLinkedListTest();
    arrayTest();
    sortingTest();
    printf("------------------------END OF TESTS--------------------------");
    return 0;
}
```